# What is the difference between uintX_n (used in IDA Pro) and unitX_t types?

Tags: ida, struct, type-reconstruction

During debugging a binary in IDA Pro, I've noticed types of the form

```
30  uint16_n                            00000002                struct {uint16_t inner;}
42  uint32_n                            00000004                struct {uint32_t inner;}
```

where the fields in each row from left to right correspond to `Ordinal`, `name`, `size`, `description` in the **Local Types** subview of IDA Pro. While the sizes seem to match the `uintX_t` counterparts, I would appreciate it if someone can explain the reasoning for introducing `uintX_n` types and the difference they have with the well known `uintX_t` types in which `X=8,16,32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems these types are custom to the program you’re analyzing and probably come from the debug information (e.g. DWARF).

The standard types from `stdint.h`are usually typedefs and not structs.